# How to retrieve javascript variable in HTML script using Python Regex?

Tags: python

```
<script>
    function foo() {
        var bar = 'thisisvalue';
    }   
</script>
```

Hi all, I have this function in script tag and I want to get the value of `var bar` by using Python regular expression. Can anyone help me with this. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the text `var bar =` won't appear elsewhere in the page?

Comment: assume `var bar =` is unique

Comment: Current code/approach ..? There are multiple steps, "get html as string", "apply regex to extract value", etc. Questions should generally provide code so that a *single* step can be focused on and explained in context what the current context. Both of the steps isolated above are already *covered in countless tutorials*.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern I always use in python is this:

```
import re
SEARCHER = re.compile( *regex with captured groups* )

...later, in a loop over lines...

  search = SEARCHER.search(line)
  if search:
     value = search.group(1)
```

In your particular case it would be something like this:

```
import re
VARBAR_SEARCHER = re.compile(r"var bar = '([^']*)'")

...

  search = VARBAR_SEARCHER.search(line)
  if search:
     value = search.group(1)
```

This omits the single quotes from the value.  If you wanted those in there you could modify the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in html:
     if 'var bar =' in line:
         thisisvalue = line.split("'")[1]
```